# Marketing Cloud: pass system VAWP view_email_url as a parameter to VF page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

We link to a customer profile center like this:

```
SET @clientkey = [Id]
SET @clientkeyencoded = URLencode(@clientkey,1,1)
SET @URLprofile = 
Concat("https://vf_page_name.secure.force.com/profile?source=marketing_mailing&id=",@clientkeyencoded)
```

and then insert the link:

```
href="%%=redirectto(@URLprofile)=%%"
```

Under certain circumstances, the VF page should forward to the web version of a newsletter after saving / updating data. To be able to do so, I wanted to pass the system-generated VAWP link in the background, so the VF page knows where to forward when the source equals "marketing_mailing". I tried to amend the standard view_email_url like this:

```
source=marketing_mailing&id=",@clientkeyencoded,view_email_url)
```

but this doesn't work.

Do I have to amend it in the redirectto somehow?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which part is not working? Are you not able to pass encoded customer id to the customer profile center?

Comment: Hi Selim,
it is about the view_email_url, as described, how to add this to the URL so the VF page then receives
profile?source=marketing_mailing&id=1234567890ABCDEF&VAWP_url
How I have to add the view_email_url to the whole string so it gets passed through properly. If I do it like described, the email is not being sent to due error without any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal way, but you can use this link in your email:

```
SET @a = view_email_url
SET @b = Substring(@a,9,600) // you should remove the first part to not make it seem like an url "https://" part.
SET @URLprofile = 
Concat("https://vf_page_name.secure.force.com/profile?source=marketing_mailing&id=",@clientkeyencoded, "&VAWP_url=", @b)
```

You should also consider "?" part in your view online URL, you may replace with with & with Replace() function.

Comment: Thanks, will try this! What do you mean by "remove first part not to make it seem like a url / https:// part"? And what do you mean by "consider ? part in your url" — the only "?" in the beginning works just fine this way. For me, I would not need "&VAWP_url=" as a parameter definition, it was just a dummy for the url, so I want to add that URL with & only. Should this work then with a ", @b" at the end?

Comment: To avoid http in http, you might use that function. Otherwise, your final URL will have something like "WAMP_url=http"

Comment: So, I got it to work — mostly. Problem is, the view_email_url is being changed from `view.mc.url.com/?qs=af3...` to `view.mc.url.com/&qs=af3...` automatically in the process, thus the link will not usable then. 
I guess you referred to this by _You should also consider "?" part in your view online URL, you may replace with with & with Replace() function._

How do I have to implement this _Replace()_? On the VF page then? Thanks for your help, again!

Comment: You can use something like that:

Replace(@a,'&,'?')

Comment: Where exactly do I have to use this? In the SET @b? In the parameter itself?

Comment: you can use it like Set @c = Replace(@b'&,'?')
then you should change your Concat function. instead of @b, you should put @c.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it — however, it doesn't seem to work: 
`SET @veu = view_email_url
SET @vawp = Substring(@veu,8,600)
SET @vawpurl = Replace(@vawp,'&','?')`
.. doesn't replace the "&".

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work this way, so I URLencode() the whole URL, which renders the Substring() shortening obsolete, too.